# How well approximated by rationals are almost all real numbers?

Tags: analytic-number-theory, continued-fractions, diophantine-approximation

Let $\psi:\Bbb{N}\to\Bbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ be such that $q\mapsto q\psi(q)$ is a (weakly) decreasing function. We say a real number $x$ is $\psi$-approximable if $|qx-p|<\psi(q)$ has solutions for arbitrarily large $q\in\Bbb{N}$ with $p\in\Bbb{Z}$.

Khinchin proved that:

- Almost every $x$ is $\psi$-approximable if $\sum_q\psi(q)$ diverges.
- Almost no $x$ is $\psi$-approximable if $\sum_q\psi(q)$ converges.

My question is about the situation where we first pick an $x$ and then ask for which $\psi$ it is $\psi$-approximable.

In particular, does almost no real number $x$ have a $\psi$ such that $x$ is $\psi$-approximable and $\sum_q\psi(q)$ converges?

Comment: Does "generic" mean "all but a Baire first category set of" or "all but a Lebesgue measure zero set of" or something else? The reason for my confusion is that it sounds like you're interested in "Lebesgue almost all" notions, but the word "generic" is nearly always associated with "Baire almost all" notions (when the choice is between these two notions).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro I'm interested in 'Lebesgue almost all'. I hadn't realised that 'generic' was used that way. I'll edit to clarify.